# Teclado movil no deja ver el formulario

Tags: html, css, formularios, teclado

Al seleccionar un campo del formulario de contacto, desde un dispositivo movil, se despliega el teclado y desordena el diseño:

Formulario sin seleccionar ningun campo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de seleccionar el campo "nombre": 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
(La sección anterior se superpone en el formulario y no deja ver lo que se escribe).

Al presionar la tecla "atras" (para que el teclado se oculte) salta a una parte de la sección anterior: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
html {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important;
}

.clearfix{
    clear: both;
}

body {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.cabecera {
background: url(../img/headerbg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
position: relative;
margin-top: 0px;
background-size: cover;
padding-bottom: 300px;
height: 100vh;
}

nav {
background: #736357;
height: 100%;
}

.logohome {
width: 60px;
margin: 15px;
}

nav {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin-top: 0px;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 0px;
float: right;
display: none;
z-index: 5;
height: 100vh;

}

nav ul li {
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
}

.logomenu { 
width: 60px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 2em;
}

.logossociales li{
display: inline;
color: #454b55;
}

.logossociales i {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
font-size: 25px;
background-color: #ffffff;
padding-top: 8px;
border-radius: 100px;
}
.logossociales {
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20px;

}
.navegacionlinks {
    column-count:2;
    column-rule: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
div.textocabecera h1 {
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-size: 2.5em;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 500;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-left: 1px;
padding-right: 1px;
padding-top: 100px;
text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.textocabecera span h2{
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,1);
font-style: italic;
}
.textocabecera h2 {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: 200;
padding-top: 0px;
text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}



.logossociales li img.redes {
    width: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

nav ul{
padding-top: 50px;
padding-left: 0px;

}

.hamburguesa {
content: url(/img/iconoham.png);
position: fixed;
top: 30px;
right: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 3;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 10px;

}

.hamactivo {
content: url(/img/hamactivo.png) ;
position: fixed ;
top: 30px ;
right: 20px ;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 7;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 10px;
}

#actividades {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important;
    background-color: #736357;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;

}
.encabezado span h2{
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.encabezado span h3{
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-style: italic;


}

.encabezado h2{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 40px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.6em;
font-weight: 700;
color: white;
}

h3 {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important;
color: white;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: 600;
text-align: center;
}
#actividades > div.contenedoractividades > div.actividadesespañol > h3:nth-child(1){
    margin-top: 0px;

}

.actividadesespañol ul li {
color: #ffffff;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;

}
.actividadesingles ul li {
    color: #ffffff;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    
    }
.actividadesespañol ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.actividadesingles ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0px;
}


.vergaleria{
position: absolute;
display: block;
float: right !important;
cursor: pointer;
top: 92%;
right: 5%;
}

.vergaleria h4{
display: block;
text-align: center;
font-size: .8em;
margin: 0 auto;
color: #ffffff;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.vergaleria i{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 auto;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #ffffff;
    }
.vergaleria a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
}
.vergaleria a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.vergaleria a:focus{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.slideruno{
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;

}
.logoslideruno{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 4;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#experiencia{
background-color: #736357;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
height: 100vh;
position: relative;

}

h1{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#experiencia h1{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#experiencia p{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.container {
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#experiencia p:last-child {
padding-bottom: 10px !important;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#comollegar{
position: relative;
background-color: #736357;
height: 100vh;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.mapagoogle{
height: 300px;
padding-bottom: 60px;
}
iframe {
    z-index: -1;
}
#comollegar img.comollegarlogo{
display: none;
}


#comollegar p{
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;

}

#comollegar p:last-child{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#comollegar > div.comollegarcolumnas > div.textocomollegar > p:nth-child(1) {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#comollegar > div.comollegarcolumnas > div.textocomollegar > p:nth-child(2){
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#contacto {
background-image: url(../img/fotocontacto.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
line-height: normal;

}

.alert{
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    margin-right: 30px !important;
    margin-left: 30px !important;
}
.matriculas h2{
font-size: 1em;
padding-top: 30px;
text-shadow: none !important;
}
.matriculas h3{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}

.telefonoscolum h3{
    text-shadow: none !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.telefonoscolum {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.telefonoscolum h3{
color: #ffffff;
padding-top: 2px !important;


}
.telefonoscolum i{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#contacto .logoslideruno{
    width: 60px;
}

#contacto h2{
text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,1);   
}
#contacto h3{
text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,1);   
}

form.formulario{
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}

form.formulario input {
    width: 80%;
}

label {
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
form.formulario textarea {
    height: 95px;
    width: 80%;
}

form.formulario label {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 10px; 
}

form.formulario input.boton{
background-color: #666666;
border: none;
color: #ffffff;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-top: 5px; 
margin-top: 6px;
}

form.formulario input.boton:hover{
    background-color: black;
}

.redesfix {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 75%;
    bottom: auto;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.redesfix i {
    
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    color: #454b55;

    }

.redesfix ul{
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}
.redesfix ul li{
    padding: 15px;
}


    
.logossocialesfooter {
    text-align: center;
}

.logossocialesfooter ul li img{
    width: 30px;
}

.logossocialesfooter ul {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
footer {
background-color: #736357;
height: 40px;    
}

footer h3{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 200;
}
footer span{
    font-weight: 300;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 374px) and (min-width: 320px) {
body {
    font-size: 13px;
}
.encabezado h2{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.textocabecera h1{
    font-size: 2.3em !important;
}
#contacto > div.columnascontacto > form > div.matriculas > h2{
    padding-top: 10px;
}
}


@media only screen and (min-width:600px){
.contenedoractividades{
    column-count:2;
    column-rule: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

nav ul li {
    padding: 2px 2px;
}

#actividades{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.logomenu{
    padding-top: 0px;
}
.navegacionlinks{
    padding-top: 0px;
}
.logossociales ul{
    padding-top: 8px;
}
}
.logoesquina {
    display: none;
}
.textomatriculas h3 {
    font-size: 0.8em !important;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
.logohome {
    width: 115px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.logomenu {
width: 115px;

}
nav ul{
    padding-top: 60px !important;
    padding-left: 0px;
    
    }
div.textocabecera h1 {
font-size: 3.3em;
letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}
.contenedoractividades ul li{
font-size: 1.5em;
} 
#actividades {
 position: relative;   
}

.actividadesespañol h3{
text-align: right;
font-size: 1.3em;
}
.actividadesingles h3{
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

.contenedoractividades ul{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.actividadesespañol ul li{
text-align: right;

}
.actividadesingles ul li{
    text-align: left;
    
    }

.logoesquina {
display: block;
position: absolute;
padding-left: 50px;
}

.logoesquina img {
    width: 80px;
}
.contenedoractividades {
padding-top: 40px;

}
h2 {
font-size: 2em;

}
h3 {
font-size: 1.3em;
}

#experiencia p{
padding-left: 60px;
padding-right: 60px;
padding-top: 20px;
font-size: 1.5em;
}
#experiencia {
 position: relative;  
 line-height: normal; 
}
#comollegar p{
padding-left: 40px;
padding-right: 40px;
font-size: 1.3em;
}
#comollegar{
    position: relative;
}
.encabezado h2{
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

.encabezado span h3{
font-size: 1.5em;

}
.comollegarcolumnas{
    /*column-count:2;
    padding-top: 40px;*/
}
.textocomollegar{
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#comollegar > div.comollegarcolumnas > div.textocomollegar > p:nth-child(1) {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#comollegar > div.comollegarcolumnas > div.textocomollegar > p:nth-child(2){
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#comollegar img.comollegarlogo{
display: block;
padding-left: 10px;
}
#comollegar h1{
position: absolute;
float: right;
}

.mapagoogle {
height: 350px;

}
.redesfix {
display: flex;
}
#contacto .logoslideruno{
    display: none;
}
.logoslideruno{
    width: 80px;
}
.columnascontacto {
   /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 60px;*/
}
.columnascontacto .encabezado{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex: 1; 
}
.columnascontacto .formulario{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
}
#contacto{
    position: relative;
}
.redesfix a{
padding-bottom: 10px;

}
.textomatriculas{
    column-count:2 !important;
    column-rule: 1px solid #ffffff !important;
}
.textomatriculas h3 {
    font-size: 0.8em !important;
}

footer h3{
    padding-top: 10px;
}

}


@media only screen and (min-width:1024px){
    .comollegarcolumnas{
        column-count:2;
        padding-top: 40px;
    }
    .columnascontacto {
        display: flex;
         flex-direction: row;
         justify-content: center;
         padding-top: 60px;
     }

     .logoesquina img {
        width: 100px;
     }

     #experiencia > p:nth-child(3) {
    padding-top: 60px;
     }
     .comollegarcolumnas{
         padding-top: 60px;
     }
     .logoslideruno {
    width: 100px;
     }
    .actividadesespañol{
    padding-right: 20px;
    }
    .actividadesingles{
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    #experiencia p {
        padding-right: 100px;
        padding-left: 130px;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    .textocomollegar p{
        padding-left: 130px !important;
        padding-right: 30px !important;
        text-align: justify !important;
    }
    #contacto > div.columnascontacto > form > div.matriculas > div.textomatriculas > h3:nth-child(1){
        text-align: right;
    }
    #contacto > div.columnascontacto > form > div.matriculas > div.textomatriculas > h3:nth-child(2){
        text-align: right;
    }
    #contacto > div.columnascontacto > form > div.matriculas > div.textomatriculas > h3:nth-child(3){
        text-align: left;
    }
    #contacto > div.columnascontacto > form > div.matriculas > div.textomatriculas > h3:nth-child(4){
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Alpaso</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/estilos.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/responsiveslides.js"></script>
    <script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsiveslides.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/logocomollegar.png" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
 <section id="comollegar">
                <div class="logoesquina">
                                <img src="/img/logoalpaso.png">
                                </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        
        <div class="encabezado">    
                <h2>Cómo llegar</h2>
                <span><h2>───────</h2></span>
                <span><h3>Location</h3></span>
        </div>
        <div class="comollegarcolumnas">
        <div class="textocomollegar">
        <p> El lugar se encuentra enclavado a orillas de Río San Pedro a 7 km  de San Clemente en el Valle de Paravachasca.
                        San Clemente se encuentra  a 1h 30 min (76 km) de la ciudad de Córdoba</p>
        <p>The place is located on the San Pedro River banks 7 km away from San Clemente in the Paravachasca Valley.
                        San Clemente is located at 1h 30 min (76 km) from the city of Córdoba.</p>
        </div>                
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="mapagoogle">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2890.450986978471!2d-64.63100868514107!3d-31.70793498130802!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zMzHCsDQyJzI4LjYiUyA2NMKwMzcnNDMuOCJX!5e1!3m2!1ses-419!2sar!4v1547557578357" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </section>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <section id="contacto">
                <div class="logoesquina">
                                <img src="/img/logoalpaso.png">
                                </div>
        <img src="img/logoalpaso.png" class="logoslideruno">

        <div class="columnascontacto">
        <div class="encabezado">    
                <h2>Contacto y <br>consultas</h2>
                <span><h2>──────</h2></span>
                <span><h3>Contact and Queries</h3></span>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        
                <form class="formulario needs-validation">
                        <div class="formuno">
                        <label>Nombre y Apellido / Name and Last Name:</label><br>
                        <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" required>
                        <br>
                        <label>Correo Electronico / Email:</label><br>
                        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
                        <br>
                        <label>Telefono / Phone:</label><br>
                        <input id="telefono" type="tel" name="telefono" required>
                        <br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="formdos">
                        <label>Mensaje / Message:</label><br>
                        <textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
                        <br>
                        <input class="boton" type="submit" value="Enviar / Send">
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="matriculas">
                                <h2>Prestadores de Turismo Alternativo de la Provincia de Córdoba Ley 8801/99</h2>
                                <div class="textomatriculas">
                                        <h3>Maglione Silvia del Valle <span>Resolución 383/18</span></h3>
                                        <h3>Celoria Jose Luis <span>Resolución 386/18</span></h3>
                                        <h3>Weller Fernando Mauricio <span>Resolución 012/19</span></h3>
                                        <h3>Sosa Enrique <span>Resolución 013/19</span></h3>
                                </div>
                                        <div class="telefonoscolum">
                                        <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>
                                        <h3>&nbsp+54&nbsp9&nbsp351&nbsp5312040&nbsp/&nbsp+54&nbsp9&nbsp351&nbsp6624403</h3>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                </form>
        
        </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                
        </section>
 <section class="redesfix">
        <div class="logossociales">
        <ul>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/alpasoaventuracba" target="blank"><li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/alpasoaventura/" target="blank"><li><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCz0ZjeYtmMcZfRSmi_BVZpQ?view_as=subscriber" target="blank"><li><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></li></a>
        </ul>
                </div>
                
 </section>

 <footer>

      <h3>Desarrollado por <span>Aybrand</span></h3>  
 </footer>
</body>
<script>
        $(function() {
          $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
        });
      </script>

      <script>
          $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
  auto: true,             // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
  speed: 500,            // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
  timeout: 4000,          // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
  pager: false,           // Boolean: Show pager, true or false
  nav: true,             // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
  random: false,          // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
  pause: false,           // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
  pauseControls: true,    // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls, true or false
  prevText: "<",   // String: Text for the "previous" button
  nextText: ">",       // String: Text for the "next" button
  maxwidth: "",           // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
  navContainer: "",       // Selector: Where controls should be appended to, default is after the 'ul'
  manualControls: "",     // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
  namespace: "rslides",   // String: Change the default namespace used
  before: function(){},   // Function: Before callback
  after: function(){}     // Function: After callback
});
      </script>
</html>
```

URL del sitio: http://alpasoaventura.com/

Gracias!

Comment: Aun no pude resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia compañero, te agradeceriamos si colocas codigo del programa para poder llegar a resolver el problema. De cualquier forma se me ocurre que puedas poner un `scrollview` para que el teclado no sobreponga  sobre el formulario. Si puedes mostrarnos tu código ayudaría mucho

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

      <Aquí tu formulario>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: No me funcionó, ya actualicé la pregunta. Gracias!

Comment: Me cofundi creí que era una app, deja checo tu código.

Comment: Hola compañero, pudiste ver mi codigo?